# LAN server - can you run a mySql database as well as a file server?

Tags: server, partitioning, mysql, samba

Looking to install ubuntu server on a specific server machine. I want to put 2 HDDs so as to have a basic RAID-1 setup.

Looking to have this act as a fileserver **and** a mySql database server (nothing too heavy/serious in terms of usage for either)

i understand the basic set up of : server-PC has a non-gui operating system, is always on, and also runs samba so as to provide connectivity to microsoft client-PCs to get access to files.

i'm unclear though whether the mySql exists essentially as a collective of files that is on the hard drive, not any different than another file (which is silently mirrored by another, higher-level process) and the entire system of "word documents" + "mySql files" is part of the "file server"

or is this structured more like:

A) 1 directory for the operating system, maybe even a separate partition for ease of recovery (not mirrored on both HDDs)

B) (over-arching RAID1 mirroring process run by the OS) -- another directory for just the "file server", samba is loaded up at boot-up, maybe on another partition

C) (over-arching RAID1 mirroring process run by the OS) -- another directory for just the database server/database service that is loaded into memory upon boot-up as well, likewise on another partition.

sorry if this is a dumb question, at one level i understand how a database file isn't distinguishable from a powerpoint presentation, but i get confused with how mySql is actually "running" the database to make it available to client front ends on networked PCs.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I misunderstand your question. You want to setup a server and are unsure about how to structure directories and how to deploy RAID?

Please allow me go just answer is a collection of unsorted items hoping some would be useful.

- If your system has Hardware RAID. use that. When you have 2 disk the only sensible option is RAID1. When you use software RAID you should cover your whole installation, not part of it.
- I would recommend to install LVM. I did not to that on my first server. It allows you to change your disk setup at any time after installation. Even while the system is running. Good thing to have
- I do install on all my servers a desktop, i.e. Xubnutu-minimal. That way I could remote login with 'ssh -X servername' and use GUI editors and file managers. For some tasks thats a lot more convenient. I would have installed the desktop version, but the desktops install CD is missing all the relevant server software
- If your install LAMP, you get apache and SQL installed with one click. Each service is setup fully running. All services have their default installation directories where they expect you to put their data. Unless you have a good reason to change that, your are better of to keep it there and change it later when you have that good reason.
- A server installation itself is quite small (a few gigs), it all depends on your data how large your disks must be. Once you got acquainted to server management you will find that you can easily spread your server installation across multiple disks later one. For example if your fileserver grows you can move a subdirectory or the full directory to another disk. So I would recommend to keep it all on a single disk
- MySQL puts all its data into a database file and communicates with their uses either via SQL queries or, more typical via a website which is using PHP or Perl scripts that query the MySQL database.
- There are 2 ways to backup a server. Make an image of the full disk. Or save single files. LVM allows you to make a data snapshot and save that while the system is running. Saving files would require you to shut down the services or you might get an inconsistent backup. The MySQL requires you to go into the Maintenace tool (a website) and save the database to a file. That can be backed up.
- There are may tools that can be used for backup. Its highly recommended to install a tool that runs a regulary (i.e. daily) backup of the server.

If you are very new to Linux servers I can recommend the "Ubuntu Server Book". It is very readable and gives a very good overview of the server, tools to use and issues you might encounter. It would have saved me quite a few hours googling when I would have bought it earlier.

Cheers
CatMan

Comment: thanks - i think i may have been asking something more simple: do you need mysql to run on your server as a program in order for there to be any accessibility to the underlying database? when I have been playing with mysql as a local install, i have to specifically "turn on" mysql server in order for me to connect to the database. if that's the same way it will operate on a server, i'm wondering how that runs simultaneously with a "file server"/program that makes the server run like a file server (like SAMBA)

Comment: You need to have it run as a program.  Using windows terms its run as a service. Its the same with Samba for file sharing and apache for web hosting. All server 'services' run as a background task waiting for something to happen, so they can react to that. Also a not very powerful computer can runs those things simultaneously, unless you would have a high number of users accessing the server at the same time doing database work, web site work , email, file work, media streaming and such. From what I saw from your description you should install all what your need and run it in parallel.